# Empty fields on update commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When using an update command there is no way to validate when a field is None by default or None due to a new value.

Thanks in advance in you can help :)

```
# views.py
class UpdateCustomerView(APIErrorsMixin, APIView):
    class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        password = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        document = serializers.CharField(required=False)

def put(self, request, id):
        input_serializer = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        input_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        cmd = commands.UpdateCustomer(id=id, **input_serializer.validated_data)
        bus = bootstrap.bootstrap()
        bus.handle(cmd)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

# commands.py
@dataclass
class UpdateCustomer(Command):
    id: UUID
    document: Optional[str] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None

# handlers.py
def update_customer(
    cmd: commands.UpdateCustomer, uow: AbstractCustomerUnitOfWork
) -> None:


    # So here comes the issue cmd.name is None because the view didn't receive it or because the dataclass of the command set its value to default?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow to ban `None` value for `name` in `InputSerializer`

```
name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=False)
```

Alternatively, you can use custom field validation to log warning or wrap the name in string.

Note from [Django doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/):

> Note: If your <field_name> is declared on your serializer with the parameter required=False then this validation step will not take place if the field is not included.

So, custom validation method will not be run if the field is not included, differentiating empty field vs field with value of `None`.

For example, custom `name` validator:

```
class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    document = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def validate_name(self, value):
        if value is None:
            logging.warning('provided name is None')
        return str(value)
```

Here it's both logging a warning and returning `'None'` string for `None` input.

Comment: Thanks for comment but i don't want to ban the "none" use, i just want a way to identify when it's set

Comment: Also if the update command set the variable as none it will cause an error when updating the data on the model because of the `allow_null = true` code so i think is no the best solution to do so

Comment: see updated answer for alternative method